# Retrieve data from Cassandra database using python

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to retrieve data from Cassandra database for multiple ids within a certain time period. For this I am using CQL query and Python DataStax library:

```
Cqlquery = “ SELECT * FROM [table name] WHERE id IN ({}) and start >= ‘{} AND start <=’{};”
```

The problem is, when I set the time frame for the selected id where the value is constant, I am not getting desired output. For example from 2021-02-10 8:00 to 2021-02-10 20:00 my query does not return any result (according to the plot below it should be ~200000) since in the database value is saved only at the time when it changes. If the time frame covers the value change (2021-02-10 22:00 to 2021-02-11 02:00) I get two results (0 and 197000).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdblP.png)

My question is how to deal with that in possibly the simplest and efficient way?
I wonder if the thing is to build an appropriate CQL query, or there are some built-in methods in DataStax lib that could deal with that automatically.
I would be grateful for some tips.

Comment: read https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/getting_started/ - it describes best practices, etc.

Comment: I think you can have a look at this problem in two parts ,


 1st part , DB part, is your query getting the data as you desire it to be ? Essentially, is it working as you expect it to be ?

2nd part : This is the programming part, are the values captured properly and processed in order, you may have to look at how you iterate and organise the data gathered from your query.